# What is the core difference and similarity between AWS-EMR, Google Dataproc and Azure HDInsight

Tags: cloud, amazon-emr, google-cloud-dataproc, azure-hdinsight

I am working on a project and for that, I need to choose between AWS-EMR, Dataproc, and Azure HDInsights. Can someone please explain the main difference in the offerings of all three?